# Borderlands 2 Is it possible to duplicate items

Tags: borderlands-2

I was just wondering weather you could dupe weapons, iv got a new orange weapon and want to give it to my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate weapons. You go in a trade. You duel them then. Equip it. Then drop it and then you run out of the duel circle and then you pick the weapon back up. They also have the weapon. You can do this with any weapon but the person who has the weapon has to be able at the required level to equipped it.

Comment: I believe this bug was patched a while ago.

Answer (score -1):

You can learn which creature drops that item and then farm until you get the item again. Other than that, there aren't any legitimate duping options. You could always just lend them the item too :p

Comment: Do you mean "there aren't any *legitimate* duping options"?